# Google ORTools CP-SAT | Get list of index of 1's from a list of ortools-variables

Tags: python, optimization, indexing, or-tools, cp-sat

I want to convert [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0] to [2, 4, 6] using ortools.

Where "2", "4", "6" in the second list are the index of "1" in the first list.

Using the below code I could get a list [0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0]. How can I get [2, 4, 6]?

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


model = cp_model.CpModel()
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()

work = {}
days = 8
horizon = 7
for i in range(days):
    work[i] = model.NewBoolVar("work(%i)" % (i))

model.Add(work[0] == 0)
model.Add(work[1] == 0)
model.Add(work[2] == 1)
model.Add(work[3] == 0)
model.Add(work[4] == 1)
model.Add(work[5] == 0)
model.Add(work[6] == 1)
model.Add(work[7] == 0)


v1 = [model.NewIntVar(0, horizon, "") for _ in range(days)]
for d in range(days):
    model.Add(v1[d] == d * work[d])


status = solver.Solve(model)
print("status:", status)

vec = []
for i in range(days):
    vec.append(solver.Value(work[i]))
print("work",vec)
vec = []
for v in v1:
    vec.append(solver.Value(v))
print("vec1",vec)
```

You should see this output on the console,

```
status: 4
work [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
vec1 [0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0]
```

Thank you.

---

Edit:
I also wish to get a result as [4, 6, 2].

Comment: 2 questions: (a) is the number of 1s fixed ? (b) do you want a list of variables with the consecutive indices, or a python list of integer with the solution ?

Comment: @Laurent (a) The number of 1s is fixed. In this case, it is 3. (b) I want a list of variables with consecutive indices.

Answer (score 2):

For just 3 variables, this is easy. In pseudo code:

- The max index is `max(work[i] * i)`
- The min index is `min(horizon - (horizon - i) * work[i])`
- The medium is `sum(i * work[i]) - max_index - min_index`

But that is cheating.

If you want more that 3 variable, you will need parallel arrays of Boolean variables that indicate the rank of each variable.

Let me sketch the full solution.

You need to build a graph. The X axis are the variables. The why axis are the ranks. You have horizontal arcs going right, and diagonal arcs going right and up. If the variable is selected, you need to use a diagonal arc, otherwise an horizontal arc.

If using a diagonal arc, you will assign the current variable to the rank of the tail of the arc.

Then you need to add constraints to make it a contiguous path:

- mass conservation at each node
- variable is selected -> one of the diagonal arc must be selected
- variable is not selected -> one of the horizontal arc must be selected
- bottom left node has one outgoing arc
- top right node has one incoming arc

Comment: Thanks for your solution for the 3 variables. But there can be more than 3 variables and we know that number, we just do not need to find out the number of 1s. I'll try writing in the way you suggested for more than 3 variables. Btw in my problem, the maximum number of 1s can be 24 (known beforehand).